# Stream inheritance: which methods to override?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I need to wrap existing `Stream` instance and implement some additional logic on reading or writing.

Wrapper must be a `Stream` too. It will be passed to the 3rd party API, which needs `Stream` (thus, I cannot extract an interface and use [`DispatchProxy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.dispatchproxy?view=netcore-3.1)).

Obvious way is to inherit from `Stream` like this:

```
public sealed class WrappedStream : Stream
{
    private readonly Stream inner;

    public WrappedStream(Stream inner)
    {
        this.inner = inner;
    }

    public override bool CanRead => inner.CanRead;

    public override bool CanSeek => inner.CanSeek;

    public override bool CanWrite => inner.CanWrite;

    public override long Length => inner.Length;

    public override long Position 
    { 
        get => inner.Position;
        set => inner.Position = value; 
    }

    public override void Flush() => inner.Flush();

    public override long Seek(long offset, SeekOrigin origin) => inner.Seek(offset, origin);

    public override void SetLength(long value) => inner.SetLength(value);

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // TODO: implement additional logic here

        return inner.Read(buffer, offset, count);
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // TODO: implement additional logic here

        inner.Write(buffer, offset, count);
    }
}
```

But all of the abstract methods in `Stream` are for synchronous I/O. I suspect, that in case of implementing abstract methods only, base `Stream` will perform async-over-sync.

Since `inner` can support async, I don't want to break this support with async-over-sync.
There are several virtual [TAP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap) and [APM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm) methods in `Stream`, but which of them should be overriden for correct asynchronous I/O support?

**Update**

I read "Notes to Implementers". Base `Stream` does async-over-sync, if inherited type doesn't implement its own `Begin...` methods. `FileStream`, for example, uses its own asynchronous implementation. So, in despite of base implementation will work, it won't be effective from async I/O perspective.

Comment: "Notes to Implementers" section at the following link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netcore-3.1) is having some of these detail.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.stream?view=netcore-3.1#notes-to-implementers):

> When you implement a derived class of `Stream`, you must provide implementations for the `Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` and `Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` methods. The asynchronous methods `ReadAsync(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`, `WriteAsync(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`, and `CopyToAsync(Stream)` use the synchronous methods `Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` and `Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` in their implementations. Therefore, your implementations of `Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` and `Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` will work correctly with the asynchronous methods. The default implementations of `ReadByte()` and `WriteByte(Byte)` create a new single-element byte array, and then call your implementations of `Read(Byte[], Int32, Int32)` and `Write(Byte[], Int32, Int32)`. When you derive from `Stream`, we recommend that you override these methods to access your internal buffer, if you have one, for substantially better performance. You must also provide implementations of `CanRead`, `CanSeek`, `CanWrite`, `Flush()`, `Length`, `Position`, `Seek(Int64, SeekOrigin)`, and `SetLength(Int64)`.
>
> Do not override the `Close()` method, instead, put all the `Stream` cleanup logic in the `Dispose(Boolean)` method. For more information, see Implementing a `Dispose` Method.

So to summarize there is a set of methods/properties that needs to be implemented:

- `Read(..)`, `Write(..)`, `CanWrite`, `Flush(..)`, `Length`, `Position`, `Seek(..)` and `SetLength(..)`.

All other virtual methodes should be overriden if you can provide a better implemention as the default one.

So if you can implement a truely async `ReadAsync(..)` and `WriteAsync(..)` you should do it. The same goes for `FlushAsync(..)`, `CopyToAsync(..)` and `DisposeAsync(..)`.

Also a look into the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/c2b10188d540c863e8233e9a556cbc7af5bfbd8d/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/IO/Stream.cs#L76-L86)

```cs
...

public virtual int ReadTimeout
{
    get => throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.InvalidOperation_TimeoutsNotSupported);
    set => throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.InvalidOperation_TimeoutsNotSupported);
}

public virtual int WriteTimeout
{
    get => throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.InvalidOperation_TimeoutsNotSupported);
    set => throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.InvalidOperation_TimeoutsNotSupported);
}

...
```

reveales that you also should override `ReadTimeout` and `WriteTimeout` if you want to support it.

Comment: "The asynchronous methods ... use the synchronous methods" - this is async-over-sync. I'll update question a little later.